# Text styles used in Settings app for titles and subtitles

Tags: android, textview

which text styles are used for the titles and subtitles in the Settings app? I tried using the following, but none of these produced the same result.

[image]

**Title text**

- `android:textAppearance="?android:titleTextAppearance"`
- `android:textAppearance="?attr/title"`

**Subtitle text**

- `android:textAppearance="?android:subtitleTextAppearance"`
- `android:textAppearance="?attr/subtitle"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text style is often not enough to achieve a particular style, you often need to set color too. In this case, I suspect they use [Google Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) styles. It's hard to judge the appropriate font size here given your font scale, but here's what I think they use:

- Title

  ```
  android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody1"
  ```
- Subtitle

  ```
  android:textAppearance="?textAppearanceBody2"
  android:textColor="@color/material_on_background_emphasis_medium"
  ```

[image]

They also use a special font.